# How to disable MLFlow temporarily?

Tags: python, machine-learning, mlflow

Is it possible to disable MLFlow temporarily for debugging code or adding new features? If it is not disabled it saves a bunch of executions not actually usefull or unfinished executions.

Or is the best strategy to use similar code that doesn't call `mlflow.start_run()`?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if there is an explicit way to disable `mlflow_start_run()` but one strategy is to use a debug flag that only calls part of that starts an `mlflow_startu_run()`.